# mongodb moving value from NumberInt to NumberLong

Tags: mongodb

We are trying to preallocate documents in a collection. Usually NumberInt for our values is sufficient. When we get 1million writes into that document (it is one doc per day time series, so 1 million is possible), then the value moves from NumberInt to NumberLong.

We are planning to disable padding, so any single byte movement will move the document.

The question is, whether mongodb will move the document if the NumberInt changes to NumberLong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MongoDB 3.0 + MMAPv1 with [`noPadding` allocation](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/collMod/#noPadding) (aka "exact fit"), then the document will *have* to move if you change from 32-bit ints (4 bytes) to 64-bit longs (8 bytes). With `noPadding` there is no extra space available to store more bytes, so you should start with NumberLongs to avoid expected document growth.

> The question is, whether mongodb will move the document if the NumberInt changes to NumberLong

You can confirm the outcome via the [database profiler](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/). Here's a quick run in the 3.0.7 `mongo` shell:

```
// Drop test collection
db.mycollection.drop();

// Create new test collection with noPadding (exact-fit allocation)
db.createCollection("mycollection", { noPadding: true });

// Enabling profiling of all operations
db.setProfilingLevel(2)

// Insert a document with a 32-bit int
db.mycollection.insert({ _id: 'nopadding', value: NumberInt(42) });

// Update document to have a 64-bit int
db.mycollection.update({ _id: 'nopadding' }, { $set: { value: NumberLong(10000000) }});

// Disable profiling
db.setProfilingLevel(0);

// Check if our update operation resulted in a move
db.system.profile.find({op:'update', 'query._id': 'nopadding', moved: true}).count()
1
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for the clarification @Stennie